# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: sql-server

I created a Stored procedure in SQL Server Standard Edition which works fine but when I am trying to apply same procedure in SQL Server Express edition but I am getting following error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
> common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
> context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
> semicolon.

Below is the piece of code where the error is coming

```
DECLARE @ProcessId AS INT

CREATE TABLE #Temp_ReadJson (
    BucketId INT, StatusType VARCHAR(50)
);

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max)=(SELECT TOP 1 ProcessJSON FROM MASTER.Process WHERE ID=@ProcessId)
        
INSERT INTO #Temp_ReadJson
SELECT BucketId, StatusType FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Connections')
WITH (BucketId INT, StatusType VARCHAR(50))--Error is coming in this line
```

what I need to do here?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return? Your statement is correct, but you need SQL Server 2016 to use built-in JSON support.

Comment: @Zhorov Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: Then probably the current database has a different compatibility level.

Comment: @Zhorov any hotfixes for this?

Comment: actually here is a syntax error you may correct the syntax error https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/

Answer (score 0):

[`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) was introduced in SQL Server 2016 so your database must be in compatibility level 130 or greater in order to use the function. Since this is apparently a development database, make sure your database has the same compatibility level as production. This can be changed `ALTER DATABASE` like the example below.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

add a semicolon before with ..

```
SELECT BucketId, StatusType FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Connections');
WITH (BucketId INT, StatusType VARCHAR(50))
```